# What is “plural of class”?

Tags: greek, grammar

I was recently having a conversation and we discussed Titus 1:6. The idea of “plural of class” was applied to tekna. I was surprised, I had never heard of this type of plural. Is there such a plural? And would tekna be one?

Titus 1:6 NIV (Greek from Westcott and Hort 1881)

> An elder must be blameless, faithful to his wife, a man whose children (τέκνα) believe and are not open to the charge of being wild and disobedient.

Comment: Tekna is just "children".  There is nothing special about this word.  It also occurs in Matt 2:18, 3:9, 7:11, etc.

Comment: The idea suggested was a method to understand a plural which could be understood as one or more. Normally plural is defined as two or more. Therefore Titus 1:6 is saying an elder is disqualified if he has only one child. My primary concern is whether there is a “plural of class”.

Comment: This is making no sense at all. A man is excluded from the position of overseer if he has more than one wife. What has that to do with children ? Typing 'plural of class' into Google or into [Stack Exchange English Language & Usage](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions) gives no returns at all. It is meaningless.

Comment: In any case, the Greek word for "class" does not occur in Titus 1:6.  I am struggling to understand what you are asking.

Comment: I've never heard of such a thing, and am also having trouble understanding this question. I suggest you ask whoever told you about it to explain it more.

Answer (score 1):

The question seems valid. A similar question can be found at this link: [https://www.ibiblio.org/bgreek/test-archives/html3/2001-11/7963.html?cmdf=greek+%22plural+of+class](https://www.ibiblio.org/bgreek/test-archives/html3/2001-11/7963.html?cmdf=greek%20%22plural%20of%20class%22)

> In his Grammar of the Greek N.T. in Light of Historical Research at p.
> 408, A.T. Robertson speaks of the "representative singular," which occurs
> when the singular is used with the article to signify the whole class....

> 5. Assuming that TEKNA in 1 Tim. 3:4 and Titus 1:6 can be read to mean
>    "one or more," is it correct to say that TEKNA is being used in those
>    passages as a "plural of class"? See Winer, A Grammar of the Idiom of
>    the New Testament (7th ed. by Lunemann), section 27, no. 2, p. 175.

The quoted reference in Winer begins here:

> 2. Conversely, the Plural of class (masc. or fem.) is used although the predicate refers primarily to only one individual, when the writer wishes to keep the thought somewhat vague; as,
>    Matt. ¡i. 20 TelUNKaGW Di ENTOUUTES ThY YUN To Taiov (Herod
>    the Great alone is meant, vs. 19), cf. Exod. ir. 19. See Aesch. Prom.
>    67; Eurip. Hec. 403; Aeschin. adv. Timarch. 21 and Bremi in loc.
>    Porson, Eur. Phoen. p. 36; Reisig, Conject. in Aristoph. p. 58, and
>    C. L. Roth, gramm. quaest. e C. Tacito. Norimb. 1829, 4to. § 1.

The discussion continues for a bit. The short explanation is that there are times languages use plurals but they aren't *specifically* meant to be plurals. The "Plural of Class" -- as explained in the quote above -- denotes times where we might use a plural for an undefined number. It may be one, two, or more.

We can see the exact same usage in English. I might ask someone, "Do you have children?" If the respondent says, "I have a son," I would not be likely to start arguing about the number of children they have. We would understand that my question was more about whether they had children, not the exact number of them.

I would say the same is true in Titus 1:6. The exact number of children is not the right focus. The focus is on the fact that any children must be believers.

As a final note (and just my opinion), some Greek scholars are fond of dividing up Greek grammar into further and further divisions. I don't believe "Plural of Class" is currently taught to Greek students as a useful point of grammar. It may have another name, or might just not be a focus in current studies, but regardless it seems to not be in favor today. The point of *this discussion* is still valid, I'm just not sure the phrase "Plural of Class" is.

Comment: Thank you, I agree that there are areas of thought which have blended into the background.  The whole concept of ‘number’ in  Greek is used hundreds of time s in reference to agreement. Certainly, the concept is not earth shaking but it might surprise us all how significant it colors our understanding.